# Brackets multiplication

Tags: c++, algorithm, multiplication

I need to have in array coefficients of polynomial in normal form, so I need to multiply long sequence of brackets:

(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)...(x-n).

How can I do it in best possible time complexity?

Answer (score 0):

Best possible time complexity isn't a good question to ask, as the best possible time isn't always the best possible complexity and there are a ton of variables that go into the best possible time.

I would highly recommend implementing a naive approach first (i.e. whatever comes to mind first). Once you have done that, see if that is fast enough, if it is, that is all that matters.

(As a side note, the naive solution is probably `O(n)` and I think the optimal solution is still `O(n)`)

Comment: I think that this problem can actually be done in constant complexity `O(1)`, using the gamma function to compute the factorial, or something like that (my maths are a bit rusty just now).

Comment: @rodrigo: It was hard to tell from the post whether they had `1..n` as the code implied, or actually `array[0]..array[n-1]`. Especially when they say "array coefficients of polynomial".

Comment: Maybe I asked a wrong question. I just didn't know how to do it. I need to keep those coefficients in an array, and I couldn't come up with naive algorithm... But I got an idea. That's still O(n^2), but I think it would be enough. I don't know how to make it in O(n), if after every multiplication I must add coefficients with the same degree of x. My algorithm: two arrays. Coefficients that I have after i multiplications will be in the first, and in every step from 1 to n I'll be doing operation tab2[j] = tab1[j-1] * i, and then for all elements tab1, tab1[j] += tab2[j]. Still looking for O(n).

Comment: @ago, 1..n, as in Lagrange formula. Sorry for grammar mistakes, in Poland we have a bit different structure of sentence.

Comment: @user3608878: It certainly sounds like you have algorithm reduction problem, where you want to take an equation and bake in some of the intermediate steps. Unfortunately this isn't the best place, you may have better luck with http://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that algorithm exists with complexity better than O(n^2). Coefficients of polynom with given roots [1..n] can be expressed through [Vieta's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas), where every coefficient is complex sum of root products. This is rather effective Delphi example (adapted from some  Fortran numerical library).
For  n =3 it produces [-6, 11, -6, 1] coefficients:

`(x-1)*(x-2)*(x-3)=x^3-6*x^2+11*x-6`

```
  procedure CalcPolyCoeff(const N: Integer; var Coeff: TArray<Integer>);
  var
    i, k: Integer;
  begin
    if N = 0 then
      Exit;
    SetLength(Coeff, N + 1);
    Coeff[0] := -1;
    Coeff[1] := 1;
    for k := 2 to N do begin
      Coeff[k] := 1;
      for i := k - 2 downto 0 do
        Coeff[i + 1] := Coeff[i] - k * Coeff[i + 1];
      Coeff[0] := -k * Coeff[0];
    end;
```