# how to find coefficients of a polynomial with roots 1 to n

Tags: algorithm, numbers, polynomial-math, number-theory, coefficients

I have a polynomial with roots `1,...,n`. I want to find all its coefficients or the sum of products of all combinations taking `i` at a time for `i in 1,...,n` first n natural numbers.
I'm not able to get a closed-form. I need something in O(n) or O(nlogn) time.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Simple quadratic algorithm [is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23498890/). O(nlogn) requires using of FFT. O(nlog^2n) approach [is described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28465398)

Comment: Thanks. This will do it.